# Unable to create a testing component in a monorepo application

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Hi all and thanks in advance for your time and knowledge.
I'm working on a monorepo application in NX workspace and switched from `jest-cypress` to `karma-protractor`, for the moment I've only one angular application (with only one component), but there are several custom libraries that the application will use. The application works fine, so I start with the writing of the test, and here is where I stop, following some tutorials I've learned that a component needs to be initialized, that here is where I stop. I've also tried to simplify my application to locate where is the problem, and it seems that at some point, during the initialization, karma will execute some other code inside a custom library. For better understanding this is my workspace:

- root

  - apps

    - application1

      - services

        - document-service
      - modules

        - test
  - libs

    - auth-lib

      - services

        - auth
      - interceptors
      - modules

        - login-module
    - common-lib

      - services

        - storage-service
        - busy-service
    - environment-lib
    - translate-lib

this is my test component:

```jsx
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DocumentService} from '../../core/api/document/document.service';
import {CommonModalService} from '@custom-library/common-module';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent {


  constructor(private documentService: DocumentService,
              private commonModal: CommonModalService,) {
  }

}
```

and this is my unit test:

```jsx
import { TestComponent } from "./test.component"
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {DocumentService} from '../../core/api/document/document.service';
import {CommonModalService, CommonModuleModule} from '@custom-library/common-module';
import {EnvironmentsModule} from '@custom-library/environments';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import {CustomTranslateModule} from '@custom-library/custom-translate';
import {AuthModule} from '@custom-library/auth-module';

describe('Testing test page', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const documentServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('DocumentService', ['']);
    const commonModalMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('CommonModalService', ['']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [TestComponent,
        { provide: DocumentService, useValue: documentServiceMock },
        { provide: CommonModalService, useValue: commonModalMock },],

    }).compileComponents();
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('creazione di HomeComponent', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

this is the `AppModule` of the `TestComponent`

```jsx
import {NgModule, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {NgxWebstorageModule} from 'ngx-webstorage';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

import {EnvironmentsModule} from '@custom-library/environments';
import {CustomTranslateLoader, CustomTranslateModule} from '@custom-library/custom-translate';
import {CommonModuleModule} from '@custom-library/common-module';
import {AuthModule} from '@custom-library/auth-module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {SharedModule} from './core/shared/shared.module';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {HomeComponent} from './modules/home/home.component';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

const appComponents = [
  HomeComponent
]

const customLibs = [
  EnvironmentsModule.forRoot(environment),
  CustomTranslateModule,
  CommonModuleModule,
  AuthModule,
]

const appModules = [
  SharedModule
]

const angularModules = [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useExisting: CustomTranslateLoader,
      deps: [PLATFORM_ID, HttpClient]
    },
  }),
  NgxWebstorageModule.forRoot({
    prefix: 'epc.poc',
    separator: '.',
    caseSensitive: true,
  }),
  FormsModule
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    appComponents,
  ],
  imports: [
    angularModules,

    AppRoutingModule,
    // custom lib modules
    customLibs,
    // ----
    appModules
  ],
  providers: [
    DatePipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this is the `AuthModule`

```jsx
import {APP_INITIALIZER, ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginComponent} from './modules/login/login.component';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {AuthRoutingModule} from './auth-routing.module';
import { AuthService } from './core/services/auth.service';
import {TokenStorageService} from './core/services/token-storage.service';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BusyService} from './core/services/busy.service';
import {UserApiService} from './core/api/identity/user-api.service';
import {AuthGuard} from './core/guards/auth.guard';
import {PermissionGuard} from './core/guards/permission.guard';
import {RoleGuard} from './core/guards/role.guard';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ErrorInterceptor} from './core/interceptors/error.interceptor';
import {JwtInterceptor} from './core/interceptors/jwt.interceptor';
import {LoadingInterceptor} from './core/interceptors/loading.interceptor';

import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {UiPermissionRouteResolveComponent} from './core/services/ui-permission-route-resolve.component';
import {UiPermissionService} from './core/services/ui-permission.service';
import {HasPermissionDirective} from './core/directives/has-permission.directive';

import {RefreshTokenService} from './core/services/refresh-token.service';
import {EpcTokenService} from './core/services/epc-token.service';

export function LoadTokenFactory(tokenService: ExternalTokenService) {
  return () => tokenService.getToken();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    UserApiService,
    AuthService,
    BusyService,
    TokenStorageService,
    EpcTokenService,
    AuthGuard,
    PermissionGuard,
    RoleGuard,
    RefreshTokenService,
    UiPermissionRouteResolveComponent,
    UiPermissionService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoadingInterceptor, multi: true },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: LoadTokenFactory,
      deps: [ExternalTokenService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  declarations: [ LoginComponent, HasPermissionDirective ],
  exports: [HasPermissionDirective]
})
export class AuthModule {
}
```

this is `TokenStorageService`

```jsx
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import {EnvironmentsConsts, EnvironmentsService} from '@custom-library/environments';
// eslint-disable-next-line @nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries
import {CommonService, StorageService, Token} from '@custom-library/common-module';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';



@Injectable()
export class TokenStorageService {
  public storedToken: Token;

  constructor(private storageService: StorageService,
              private commonService: CommonService,
              private http: HttpClient, private envService: EnvironmentsService) {
    this.storedToken = new Token();
  }

  getToken() {
    return new Observable<Token>((observer) => {
      const watcher = this.envService.isEnvironmentLoaded.subscribe((isLoaded) => {
        if (isLoaded) {
          if (EnvironmentsConsts.production) {
            watcher.unsubscribe();
            this.http.get<Token>(EnvironmentsConsts.tokenPath).subscribe((token) => {
              this.setStorageToken(token);
              observer.next(token);
              observer.complete();
            }, (error) => {
              console.log('error');
              observer.error(error);
              observer.complete();
            });
          } else {
            observer.next(this.storedToken);
            observer.complete();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  getStorageToken(): string {
    ...
  }

  getStorageRefreshToken(): string {
    ...
  }

  setStorageToken(data: Token | null): void {
    ...
  }

}
```

this is the `StorageService`

```jsx
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import {LocalStorageService} from 'ngx-webstorage';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService,
              private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {
  }

  public setItem(key: string, value: string): void {
    ...
  }

  public getItem(key: string): string {
    ...
  }

  public removeItem(key: string): void {
    ...
  }

}
```

somehow, the test fails at the `configureTestingModule`, when it tries to pass CommonModalService to the TestComponent, this is my karma log

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'StorageService')
> at Module.StorageService (login.component.ts:12:28)
> at Module.9571 (:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/libs/auth-module/src/lib/core/services/token-storage.service.ts:15:39)
> at **webpack_require** (:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> at Module.2944 (loading.interceptor.ts:13:32)
> at **webpack_require** (:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> at Module.2150 (ui-permission.service.ts:6:33)
> at **webpack_require** (:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> at Module.7346 (index.ts:13:46)
> at **webpack_require** (:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> at Module.3835 (test.ts:20:29)

As you can see, karma is trying to execute code inside a custom library and the part that I don't understand is that this library isn't used in my component.
Is there a way to control this behavior of karma?

Comment: It seems you should also mock `StorageService` and provide it in your test module.

Comment: I did it, nothing has changed, same error. I don't know why this happens

Comment: The error is about `StorageService`, but this service is otherwise not referenced anywhere in the code you pasted, so it is impossible to understand why specifically your test is complaining about the fact it can't be found somewhere.

Comment: @JoannaFalkowska , Exactly, `StorageService`, in this case, is used by `TokenSerivice` that is inside `AuthModule`. I'd like to understand why `AuthModule` is initialized, and how I can mock an `AuthModule` to avoid these kinds of problem

Comment: Otherwise I have to change, again, the test bed engine from karma to jest. With jest I had other problems (lack of my experiece) but at least I manage to inizialize `TestComponent`

Comment: @Carmy But the feature code that you pasted doesn't mention `StorageService`, `TokenService`, or `AuthModule`. I don't understand why would they be needed for the `TestComponent` to work. Is `AuthModule` imported by the module that declares your component? Or how are those things related to your component at all? Can you add to your post the bits of feature code that make use of these services and the module? Also, are those services defined with `providedIn`, or provided somewhere else?

Comment: @JoannaFalkowska you are totally right, I didn't because `TestComponent` didn't import `AuthModule`, to answer your question, those services have only `@Injectable()` without `providedIn`

Comment: Ok, I did a try, I've added`{
  providedIn: 'root'
}` but the test continue to fail at the same point.

Comment: @JoannaFalkowska I added the missed components, hope that this will help to figure out what is happening